# Click listener not working outside the viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have an activity that calls inside a custom viewpager, the top of the layout is a relative layout define the header which includes an ImageView and the rest of the view page 
When trying to initialize the viewPager the events, unlike OnClickListener, do not give any response, when commenting on the initialization everything back to work properly

```java
        btnback = findViewById(R.id.profile_btnback);


        btnback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "hello daddy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


     //   mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        setupViewPager(mViewPager);
        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

I expect to display the Toast, but the actual output is nothing without getting any crash

Comment: where are the crash logs?

Comment: There is not crash :: this what i mean https://imgur.com/YCuQiLM